# Knockoutjs and binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm going crazy with knockuoutjs and binding:

I have defined a CreateEditGroup.js document and I have created methods and Collection to retrieve or update a Group in my application:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var GroupID = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);


var Group = function (group)
{
    var self = this;
    self.GroupID = ko.observable(group ? group.GroupID : 0).extend({ required: true });
    self.Name = ko.observable(group ? group.Name : '').extend({ required: true });
};

var GroupCollection = function () {
    var self = this;
    if (GroupID == 0) {
        self.group = ko.observable(new Group());
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Group/GetGroupByID/' + GroupID,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                self.group = ko.observable(new Group(json));
            }
        });
    }

    self.backToGroupList = function () { window.location.href = '/App/Groups' };

    //Aggiunta o modifica

    self.saveGroup = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: (self.group().GroupID > 0 ? 'PUT' : 'POST'),
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: urlContact + (self.group().GroupID > 0 ? '/UpdateGroup?id=' + self.group().GroupID : '/SaveGroup'),
            data: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.group())),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = '/App/Groups';
            },
            error: function (err) {
                var err = JSON.parse(err.responseText);
                var errors = "";
                for (var key in err) {
                    if (err.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        errors += key.replace("group.", "") + " : " + err[key];
                    }
                }
                $("<div></div>").html(errors).dialog({ modal: true, title: JSON.parse(err.responseText).Message, buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } } }).show();
            },
            complete: function () {
            }
        });
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(new GroupCollection());
```

And the view that shows the form have this HTML code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateEditGroup";
}

<h2>Nuovo gruppo</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="1">

        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tbody data-bind="with: Group">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="input-large" data-bind="value: Name" placeholder="Nome" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-small btn-success" data-bind="click: saveGroup">Salva</button>
<input class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="button" value="Annulla" data-bind="click: $root.backToGroupList" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Repository/CreateEditGroup.js")"></script>
```

Everytime that I load the CreateEditGroup page I receive the message that is impossibile to bind Name attribute, but the code seems good.

Help me, please.

Code error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred at line 1936 column 17 in http://localhost:2297/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js

0x800a139e - Run-time JavaScript: Unable to parse bindings.

Message: ReferenceError: 'Name' is not defined;

Bindings value: value: Name
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message!

Comment: In your sample you nowhere have `data-bind="with: Name"`! You only have `data-bind="with: Group" ` and `data-bind="value: Name"` so your sample and the error do not match!

Comment: I have post the correct error!
I have made some test and I have post a wrong message!
Sorry!

Comment: OP is already mentioning in comments this question is now obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this puzzle!
The error is simply: in CreateEditGroup.js I have declared a variable that have called Group and an object called group

```
var Group = function (group)
{
    var self = this;
    self.GroupID = ko.observable(gruppo ? gruppo.GroupID : 0).extend({ required: true });
    self.Name = ko.observable(gruppo ? gruppo.Name : '').extend({ required: true });
};
```

I have modified the name of the object passed in this function with another name and finally works!

```
var Group = function (gruppo)
{
    var self = this;
    self.GroupID = ko.observable(gruppo ? gruppo.GroupID : 0).extend({ required: true });
    self.Name = ko.observable(gruppo ? gruppo.Name : '').extend({ required: true });
};
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a capitalization error.

```
data-bind="with : Group"
```

Should be

```
data-bind="with : group"
```

Comment: It says that "group" is undefined :(